# Why does fsck.vfat throw “Contains a free cluster (8). Assuming EOF.”?

Tags: linux, fat32, tails

I am experiencing a strange edge case where mounted VeraCrypt volume mounts and becomes read-only on Tails.

Running `fsck.vfat` reveals cluster error with a folder called “Monero”.

Trying to debug error… would you happen to know what is going on?

Thanks for helping out!

```
$ sudo fsck.vfat -r /dev/mapper/veracrypt1
[sudo] password for amnesia:
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x25: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
/Monero/Donations/Donations
  Contains a free cluster (8). Assuming EOF.
/Monero/Donations/Donations
  File size is 4448713 bytes, cluster chain length is 0 bytes.
  Truncating file to 0 bytes.
Reclaimed 4889 unused clusters (5006336 bytes).
Perform changes ? (y/n) n
/dev/mapper/veracrypt1: 22 files, 104/50728 clusters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a VFAT file system, you have a table named the FAT (File allocation table) which indicates for each cluster (group of several  block) of the disk :

- if the cluster is free or not ;
- when the cluster belongs to a file, which is the next cluster.

Here, you have a file which is declared of size 4448713 bytes, and whose the first cluster is the 8th according to information from the directory it belongs. However, the FAT indicates that the cluster 8 is free which is inconsistent. Then `fsck.vfat` proposes you the truncate the file to size 0 which makes the file system consistent again.

You have typically this kind of behaviour if you eject physically a flash drive when Windows is writting something on it : it had the time to update the directory but not the FAT.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Frédéric. Would using ext4 vs FAT32 help mitigate these types of issues?

Comment: Also, is there a way to fix inconsistency other than using `fsck.vfat` which truncates file to 0 bytes rendering it’s content inaccessible?

Comment: Yes, ext4 or xfs should be immune of such issue : each time the metadata are changed, a journal is written which gives useful hints to repair the filesystem. However, this doesn’t prevent a file to be corrupted (half written) this explain why databases system use a journal too. (Even some embedded databases like sqlite).

Comment: The dosfstools sources are public, then you can adapt it to get other behaviour than the builtin. But this would send us far away from a superuser question. The main issue is whether the FS is defragmented. If yes, you can assume each block n to have a successor n+1. This hypothesis help me to salvage a whole FS corrupted by the Chernobyl virus. If the FS is corrupted, depending of the circonstances, you may also have your file half written, then nothing can be done to salvage it.